# What verb means letting a tenant use your property for money?

Tags: verbs

Rent: paying money for using someone's property
What verb means: getting money to allow someone to use your property?

---

Added later when received an answer for British:
I am asking about American English

Answer (score 1):

(British) The landlord **lets** their property.

You can also use "leases" or (American) "rents out".

In fact "rent" is also used to mean "to get money": "The old lady rented me her her spare bedroom."

So in American English "rent" can mean both pay and get money.

> I rented the apartment from the lady, and she rented it to me.

There is also a technical difference between "let" and "lease", but you'd need to be a property lawyer to understand it.

Comment: What about American English?

Comment: "rent out" is probably fine.

Comment: Definitely rent out or just rent. I'm so sorry English is like this.